# What is an item called when it's never been changed in appearance or ingredients

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an item called when it has never been changed. In appearance or ingredients

Answer (score 1):

An item that has never changed in appearance or ingredients would usually be referred to as the **original** item.

> [**original**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/original)
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Present or existing from the beginning; first or earliest.
>    -- *‘the original owner of the house’*
>    -- *‘the plasterwork is probably original’*
> 2. Created personally by a particular artist, writer,
>    musician, etc.; not a copy.
>    -- *‘original Rembrandts’*
> 3. Not dependent on other people's ideas; inventive or novel.
>    -- *‘a subtle and original thinker’*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

The sense that suits the context of your question would be definition #1.

I'd have thought you could also use *original* as a noun ("I don't like the modern remakes; I prefer the *originals*"), but it would seem I'm wrong: the noun form has a more limited usage.

> NOUN
>
> 1. The earliest form of something, from which copies may be made.
>    -- *‘the portrait may be a copy of the original’*
> 2. An eccentric or unusual person.
>    -- *‘he was one of the true originals’*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

This restricted application of the noun form is confirmed by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/original) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/original) dictionaries.